# Rails app database connection with SQL GUI application on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, sqlyog

I'm developing rails app on windows 10. I want a GUI for default sqlite database for my app, for this I've downloaded SQLyog software: https://www.webyog.com/

Now SQLyog is asking for some credentials (e.g. host, username, password, port) to connect to my rails app database. Here, I don't know where to find these credentials for my app database.

I've checked `database.yml` file but there is no such information. Where do I find this information?

Comment: I don't see anything in the features for SQLyog that specify it works with sqlite databases. There are some other GUIs [mentioned on this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332250/windows-gui-tool-for-sqlite3)

Comment: Well, thanks your mentioned software really works with sqlite.